# 6v/12v Dc motor runs and stops for 0.5 seconds (cycle repeats)

Tags: power-supply

although am an electronic hobbyist,but i have pretty much just the basic knowledge about electronics and here's a problem that I am facing. I am using a toy dc motor that runs on 3v/6v/12v. It runs fine on batteries and power supplies (adapters) of 5v & 500mA. But when i connect a 12v & .5A adapter the motor runs and stops for half a second and this repeats. 
The power supply is fine so is the dc motor. And the motor is connected directly to the power supplies.

Comment: The power supply might be shutting off due to overcurrent; motors draw a lot of current when they first start up and some power supplies will automatically disconnect the output if something tries to draw too much current. But that's just a guess.

Comment: What kind of motor is it? Post a photo.

Comment: Did you measure the power supply if it didn't lost the output voltage? With 0.5s intervals it shouldn't be a problem with just multimeter.

Answer (score 1):

DC motors draw up to 10x the rated current based on Ohm's Law and the DC resistance of the coils.

5V/DCR < 0.5A    ok
12V/DCR > 0.5A   shutdown  (overcurrent)

Measure your DCR and then size power source appropriately or use the Molex plug on your PC which can supply 5A easily with a low ESR cap near driver.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but I am now a little confused. As i said i connected this 3v/6v/12v dc motor and doesn't run properly and stops,while this is because the motor draws a lot of current. But then why does a 12v/24v Dc motor runs fine with the same power supply of 12v 500mA.